# How to validate a Phone Number With `-` and spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate the phone number Like `1-12 -123` using regex and I have tried like

```
/^[0-9 -]+$/
```

and

```
/^[0-9,\- ]+$/
```

Iam using it like

```
/^[0-9 -]+$/.test(value)
```

And it is accepting `0-9` numbers and `-` also but not accepting the spaces.I have tried in many ways but did'nt got any solution.Can anyone suggest me.Thanks in Advance

Comment: phone number for what region?

Comment: @subzero you gave the same that I have asked...Open the link

Comment: Does `/^[0-9-\s]+$/` work for you

Comment: Have you try without ^ and $ ?

Comment: `/^[0-9 -]+$/` is working for me, it returns true on `1-12 -123`, are you sure the problem is on the regex expression?

Comment: `/^[0-9 -]+$/.test(value)` will not match anything in PHP... `.` is for concatenation !

Comment: Which language are you using? Is this JavaScript? PHP? Something else?

Comment: Iam using it in Javascript form validation

Comment: @Gautam3164 What about page language, HTML, PHP? And why are you using JS to validate? You (must) know better than anyone else that people can disable JS, and is not a good method to use. Why not use via serverside instead?

Comment: @Gautam3164 Then I don't see the problem `alert(/^[0-9 -]+$/.test("1-12 -123"));` returns true in JSfiddle. Are you **sure** about your value variable?

Comment: Fref -ii- I accept you but I just need that in javascript itself

Comment: Because none of us has been able to reproduce your problem, I'm voting to close because of the SCCEE reason.

Comment: show us the code, I've tried both in php and javascript and it finds the pattern xD

Comment: @Gautam3164 My guess you need to add `return` as in `function validateEmail(value) { var re = /^[0-9 -]+$/; return re.test(value); }`

Comment: My guess is: Your `value` variable is really not what you think it is.

Comment: @Gautam3164 Did you [try my last suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495232/how-to-validate-a-phone-number-with-and-spaces#comment28917213_19495232) ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `[ -0-9]+` (leave a space after the first square bracket) to allow spaces, dashes and numbers

Comment: @Gautam3164 Show the code you are using together with the regex. (Edit your question and provide this, do not post that code in a comment)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg see my edit once...BTW I didnt gave any code in my comment

Comment: @Gautam3164 sorry, didn't see how much reputation you had :) I guess you're quite used to StackOverflow then so you know better than to post a lot of code in a comment :P

Answer (score 0):

What I'd recommend is trimming out the spaces and the - from the field, and then validate the digits only.
Because I doubt

```
-----0-4  023 - 331 34    124
00000                      -
-
```

etc

should be considered a valid phone-numbers?

And if you then try to make a phone-number regex to take that into considerations you'll either not succeed, or run into an expression that's so complex that it's not maintainable.

So instead trim your input/format your input into a format you control, which you then easily can validate and use that.

If you really want to go a Regular Expression route, I'd think something like

```
^[1-9]([ \-0-9][0-9]+)+$
```

is what you're after.
(if the number must not start with 0, otherwise replace the first [1-9] with [0-9])
Also change the final + into {0;y} for how many blocks of numbers you allow etc if there's a limit/focus on how many 'blocks' of numbers you allow.
Regular expressions can quickly become very complex.

Answer (score 0):

For javascript :

```
var phoneNumber = "1-12 -123";
var test = /^[0-9 -]+$/.test(phoneNumber);

alert(test); // Here, return true
```

---

If you code in PHP, this code will match your phone number.

```
<?php

$phoneNumber = '1-12 -123';

if(preg_match('/^[0-9 -]+$/', $phoneNumber)) {
    echo "Phone number is valid";
}
```

Edit: Ok, use the right tag next time.

Answer (score 0):

this one works `[0-9 -]+`, this doesn't work `[0-9- ]+` (order matters)

Answer (score -2):

For spaces you need to put a `\s` in your alphabet.

```
/^[0-9\s-]+$/
```

Comment: `\s` is not only a simple space like ' ' but can be a tab, a new line, a carriage return etc.

Comment: `\s` matches more than just spaces, it matches all whitespace characters.

Comment: **Warning:** \s also includes other types of whitespace!